# TypeORM migration:run not working errno: -3008,getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, typeorm

Do you know why I get the following error when I try to run typeorm:run to execute migration?

```
node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:run
Error during migration run:
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND users-service-db
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:69:26) {
errno: -3008,
code: 'ENOTFOUND',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'users-service-db',
fatal: true
 }
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

my config is

```
users-service-db:
   environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
     - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
   image: mysql:5.7.20
   ports:
     - "7201:3306"
```

the users-service-db is running does this `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND users-service-db` say that the host doesn't know what to do. Can you help?

After trying Answer 1 and 2 still getting the same error don't know what to do it worked before?

```js
version: "3"
services:
  api-gateway:
    build:
      context: "."
      dockerfile: "./api-gateway/Dockerfile"
    depends_on:
      - chat-service
      - users-service
    ports:
      - "7000:7000"
    volumes:
      - ./api-gateway:/opt/app

  chat-service:
    build:
      context: "."
      dockerfile: "./chat-service/Dockerfile"
    depends_on:
      - chat-service-db
    ports:
      - "7100:7100"
    volumes:
      - ./chat-service:/opt/app

  chat-service-db:
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
    image: mysql:5.7.20
    ports:
      - "7200:3306"

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "7300:80"
    volumes:
      - ./phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php

  users-service:
    build:
      context: "."
      dockerfile: "./users-service/Dockerfile"
    depends_on:
      - users-service-db
    ports:
      - "7101:7101"
    volumes:
      - ./users-service:/opt/app

  users-service-db:
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
    image: mysql:5.7.20
    ports:
      - "7201:3306"
    hostname: 'localhost'
```

finally I resolved the error thanks to @Eranga Heshan

I created an additional ormConfig.js file at pasted this:

```js
export = {
  "type": "mysql",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 7201,
  "username": "root",
  "password": "password",
  "database": "db",
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": false,
  "entities": [
  "src/entities/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "migrations": [
  "./src/db/migrations/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "cli": {
  "entitiesDir": "src/db/entities",
  "migrationsDir": "src/db/migrations"
  }
 }
```

then

```
node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:run --config src/db/migrations/ormConfig
```

Comment: How are you trying to run the migration? Are you trying to run it inside the container or in your terminal?

Comment: Inside the vs code terminal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your VS Code terminal is running inside your machine. So it can't resolve `users-service-db` host.

You can do this in two ways.

#### 1. Using a new config file and execute migrations from your `localhost`

- Create a new typeorm connection config file `migrationsOrmConfig.ts` and put it inside your project (Let's say you put it in `src/migrations` directory)

  ```
  export = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '7201',
    type: 'mysql',
    user : 'root',
    password : 'password',
    database : 'db' ,
  };
  ```
- Now you can modify the command you used earlier to run migrations

  ```sh
  node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:run --config src/migrations/migrationsOrmConfig
  ```

#### 2. Execute migrations from a terminal within the container

- In your VSCode terminal type

  ```sh
  docker ps -a
  ```
- Get the `CONTAINER ID` of `user-service` (Let's say it is `CONTAINER_ID`)
- Open up a terminal inside the container

  ```sh
  docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash
  ```
- Execute the command you used earlier to run migrations (if the following command complained about `typeorm` node module not being found, you can install it inside the container)

  ```sh
  node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:run
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. First step i tried but still the same =>PS C:\Users\edibi\eclipse-workspace\nodejsSocketTypescriptGraphQL\users-service> node --require ts-node/register .\node_modules\typeorm\cli.js --config .\src\db\migrations\typeOrmConfig.ts migration:run
Error during migration run:
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND users-service-db
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:69:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'users-service-db',
  fatal: true
}
When execute step 2 it says =>/bin/sh: 1: node: not found

Comment: Okay, I updated the migration command in my 1st answer. For the second one, I made a mistake by asking you to go into the MySQL container. Can you try 1st answer again? For the 2nd, are you using docker-compose to run your backend? If so, can you share the full docker-compose file?

Comment: okey you moved typeorm migrations:run command to the front. That's ok but the error won't go away. Thanks i edited the docker-compose.yml file

Comment: No worries, based on your docker-compose file, I updated my second answer, could you try it now?

Comment: yes i think we are on the right path it seems that typeorm is not in the node-modules folder for whatsoever reason. it cannot find the typeorm package in node-modules: Error: Cannot find module '/opt/app/node_modules/typeorm/cli.js' So why it is not installing the package in the image

Comment: Do you have `typeorm` in `package.json`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232138/discussion-between-eranga-heshan-and-edibisic).